# Is it possible to add a reminder to iPhone's calendar from another iPhone native app?

Tags: iphone, calendar, reminders

I have seen somewhere that you can't add a reminder to iPhone calender from another native application programatically .

Is it true or false ? If false then how can we achieve that . If true then is there any other way of adding reminder to iPhone calendar or you can't do it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no public API to interact with the calendar store at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to do this at the moment is to publish the reminders to a calendar you host, and get the user to subscribe to it via CalDav. This is what Toodledo does. Although it requires the user to manually subscribe to the calendar.

The other option is to bypass the calendar and push notifications to the user as a reminder. This is not as resilient as the first method.

As with all these missing features, file a bug with Apple.